# Which Linux driver does control the PMIC of the Raspberry Pi 3B+?

Tags: power-management, pi-3b+

The Raspberry Pi 3B+ contains the MaxLinear (previously Exar) MxL7704 power management chip (PMIC) with I<sup>2</sup>C interface for "on-line" reconfiguration of power sequencing and internal voltages.<sup>[1](http://www.maxlinear.com/maxlinears-mxl7704-power-management-ic-powers-the-raspberry-pi-3-model-b/)</sup> This is the first time a Raspberry Pi contains a software programmable power management chip. Which driver configures power management with this chip ?

Comment: Grepping through the latest Pi kernel (4.16.0) .c, .h, and Kconfig files for "7704", "Exar", and "MaxLinear" doesn't show anything appropriate.  I guess there could be a generic interface but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

The PMIC of the Raspberry PI 3B+ is not controlled by Linux, but the closed-source firmware<sup>[1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=212833#p1312160)</sup>.